# Как отправить сообщение в telegram от пользователя к пользователю в web telegram используя javascript?

Tags: javascript, telegram, chrome-extension

Собственно вопрос в самом заголовке. Ради интереса решил сделать расширение которое добавит новый функционал в веб версию телеграмма. Но соответственно столкнулся с проблемой как отправить сообщение. Изначально пробовал использовать click функцию на кнопки отправки, но почему-то не реагирует. Пробовал так же заглядывать в network через devtools посмотреть какие запросы уходят, чтобы попробовать их так же отправить, но само сообщение которое передается зашифровано в крякозябры. То есть если копировать этот запрос то к примеру получим что-то такое:

`fetch("https://venus.web.telegram.org/apiw1", {"credentials":"omit","headers":{"accept":"*/*","accept-language":"ru-RU,ru;q=0.9,en-US;q=0.8,en;q=0.7","sec-fetch-dest":"empty","sec-fetch-mode":"cors","sec-fetch-site":"same-site"},"referrer":"https://web.telegram.org/","referrerPolicy":"no-referrer-when-downgrade","body":"L\u0007è{Uâîè+ÌÖ£Ý**много крякозябр**Lââ\t§","method":"POST","mode":"cors"});`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
document.querySelector( "button[type='submit']" ).dispatchEvent(new Event('mousedown', { bubbles: true}));
```

Answer (score -2):

С вас *двадцатьпяпь тысяч бублей*, вроде работает - клацает ентер по инпуту, а т.е. отправляет смску, на этом сайте https://web.telegram.org

```js
$('body').append(`<script id="deleteme">(()=>{
    const elm = document.querySelector('.composer_rich_textarea');
    const evt = new Event('keydown');
    evt.keyCode = 13;
    elm.focus();
    elm.dispatchEvent(evt);
})()</script>`);
$('#deleteme').remove();
```

Comment: кто дизлайки ставит вообще? код же работает